# Model Manager filtering on Boolean causing IntegrityError

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin, geodjango

I am using a Manager on a model based on a Boolean field to filter the objects displayed on the site while showing all objects in the admin unfiltered. The idea is that user's are submitting Locations but I do not want them to show on the site until they have been verified as a valid location based on my criteria.

**models.py**

```
class LocationManager(models.GeoManager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(LocationManager, self).get_query_set().filter(verified=True)

class Location(models.Model):
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = LocationManager()
    admin_objects = models.Manager()
```

**admin.py**

```
class LocationAdmin(admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = self.model.admin_objects.get_query_set()
        return qs

admin.site.register(Location, LocationAdmin)
```

In the admin, when I go into a record and check the verified Boolean to True and press save, I get an IntegrityError:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "localshare_location_pkey"
```

This worked on another project when default was True and I filtered for False. I am using Postgres. Does anyone know why this is not working or have suggestions for a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `filter()` clause? Did you change anything about your database structure and not sync the db correctly?

Comment: @lazerscience, Yes it works without the filter. I am using south for db migrations and the db is up to date.

Comment: can you post a traceback where the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, this is the answer provided by the django IRC channel. The admin looks for the first Manager by default. All I had to do was flip the order they showed up in the Model. Even with the admin.py overriding queryset and pointing to the other Manager, the order is important.

**fixed models.py**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin_objects = models.Manager()
    objects = LocationManager()
```

Comment: Some hardcore stuff right there, buddy! Still working in 1.7, cheers!